# Does java provide API's for laptop connectivity using bluetooth

Tags: java, bluetooth

Does java provide API's for laptop connectivity using bluetooth

Answer (score 1):

Heres a couple of links I found by googling:

- [www.javabluetooth.com](http://www.javabluetooth.com/)
- [www.avetana-gmbh.de/avetana-gmbh/produkte/jsr82.eng.xml](http://www.avetana-gmbh.de/avetana-gmbh/produkte/jsr82.eng.xml)
- [www.jsr82.com/jsr-82-sample-device-discovery](http://www.jsr82.com/jsr-82-sample-device-discovery/)
- [code.google.com/p/bluecove](http://code.google.com/p/bluecove/)
- [www.jarvana.com/jarvana/view/net/sf/bluecove/bluecove/2.1.0/bluecove-2.1.0-javadoc.jar!/index.html](http://www.jarvana.com/jarvana/view/net/sf/bluecove/bluecove/2.1.0/bluecove-2.1.0-javadoc.jar!/index.html)
- [raquibulbari.wordpress.com/category/bluecove](http://raquibulbari.wordpress.com/category/bluecove/)

Answer (score 1):

http://www.javabluetooth.com/development_kits.html

Of that, Bluecove is typically what you may want to use, as it works in J2SE, and if FOSS (LGPL licensed).

Answer (score 0):

Yes. There is the Java Bluetooth API. It is designed for use in J2ME runtimes. Note that your device needs to support the Blutooth API. As of now, there are several mobile phone vendors that provide the vendor support for this.